# How do I fix a dark screen on HP Folio 13?

Tags: hp

I am running Ubuntu 12.10.

Someone can explain me how to do to see in my notebook, because works perfectly but has a lighted display, I love Ubuntu and I use it on my notebook, thanks.

<sub>This is an automated translation from [the original question in Spanish](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/310796/1).</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is an English-only site. Please write your posts in English.

Comment: @gertvdijk Or, someone can translate this into English.  Like you did.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search yielded this post in the forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1913496

Try using this command on the shell:

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=90
```

If you want you can change the last number for any hexidecimal number from 00 to FF.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is an English-only site. Please do not continue in Spanish here. We have [localized Ubuntu forums](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/local-language) if you need to post in Spanish.

Comment: I posted in both spanish and english because since the question was posted in spanish it seemed like the best way to help @gabriel to get the answer